# JSON Parsing with JQ

Tags: json, jq

Original JSON

```
{
  "twitter.com": [
    {
      "source_type": "Search",
      "visits": [
        {
          "date": "2023-01-01",
          "organic": 277102097.489145,
          "paid": 84057.14235268807
        },
        {
          "date": "2023-02-01",
          "organic": 251621802.6924125,
          "paid": 71498.10105463082
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What I'm trying to get

```
{
      "source_type": "Search",
      "visits": [
        {
          "date": "2023-01-01",
          "organic": 277102097.489145,
          "paid": 84057.14235268807
        },
        {
          "date": "2023-02-01",
          "organic": 251621802.6924125,
          "paid": 71498.10105463082
        }
      ]
}
```

Essentially, in the JSON that I'm trying to query, the relevant values for me are inside an array whose key is a domain **twitter.com**. This is a user input hence, I'm unaware of how to variably check for that input every time so it would be best if I could automatically be able to get the data inside the array.

Is this possible?

Comment: What you are trying to get is not valid JSON. Objects (using curly braces `{…}`) need string keys for their values. But if you just mistyped `{…}` for `[…]` (getting an array), just extract the outer field: `jq '."twitter.com"' input.json`.

Comment: apologies, this has been fixed now

Comment: To get the first array item, use `jq '."twitter.com"[0]'` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/o2knCHvP1NK). If you want all array items, omit the index: `jq '."twitter.com"[]'` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/0SucFE-Qklf).

Comment: That wont solve the issue as the domain is a user input hence I want some way of either (i) the input being known so I can easily query it or (ii) remove the domain array all together, making its inner elements accessible

Comment: Then how about `jq '.[][]'`?

Comment: What should happen if the array contains multiple items?

Comment: Perhaps `."twitter.com"[]` or `."twitter.com"|first` is already a sufficient solution? Or really just `.[][]` as suggested by pmf

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is extract the first item of each array property (regardless of name), the following should work:

```
.[]|first
```

This will produce a stream of new objects.

Perhaps you are interested in all values of the `twitter.com` property (again, as stream, not as array):

```
."twitter.com"[]
```

Or you want all nested array elements as stream, not only the first one?

```
.[][]
```

Or are you looking for the first property in the object?

```
to_entries|first.value[]
```

Or are you really asking for how to pass variables to jq?

```
jq --arg domain twitter.com '.[$domain][]'
```

The output – for your given sample input – regardless of which option you choose, will be:

```json
{
  "source_type": "Search",
  "visits": [
    {
      "date": "2023-01-01",
      "organic": 277102097.489145,
      "paid": 84057.14235268807
    },
    {
      "date": "2023-02-01",
      "organic": 251621802.6924125,
      "paid": 71498.10105463082
    }
  ]
}
```